# Python library for using AMQP (RabbitMQ) as a transport layer for Apache Thrift RPC

Tags: python, rabbitmq, thrift, amqp

Can anyone recommend me a Python library for using AMQP (preferable RabbitMQ) as a transport layer for Apache Thrift?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use Thrift to serialize messages to binary data,
you can use any of the Python clients on this page: http://www.rabbitmq.com/devtools.html

In the end, rabbitmq messages are just binary data which is exactly what thrift produces.

I did something similar with Google Protocol Buffers and c# here: http://itcrowd.be/rabbitmq-and-protobuf
You could apply the same logic to your python + thrift solution.

In the end, rabbitmq does not care what the message contains as long as it's an array of bytes.

Comment: Thank you for the example with Protocol buffer, but there is a difference: you only use Protocol buff for the message format, while I intend to use Apache Thrift for RPC. And I don't want RabbitMQ to know anything about what procedure was called from the ones declared in the .thrift file.

Comment: I see, in that case I cannot offer more suggestions, sorry :)